# PHP file-upload not working

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm having trouble moving the file. I'm also wondering if there's a way for a user to upload a different picture, and have it automatically remove the old one?

```
move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],"userdata/".$_POST['username']."/profilepic".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Dont suppress the errors using `@` and see what you get.

Comment: Are you sure the *relative* path to your destination exists and is writable? Also, to overwrite old ones, simply use a static filename (you are already in a distinct user's directory...)

Comment: Make sure you have write permission on the folder you're uploading the picture

Comment: @Deepak its still not working, its not moving the file to the correct place

Comment: its moving to userdata\plmexico\profilepic ,, but the plmexico is a user

Comment: Ofcourse it will place the pic inside a folder named after a user since you're specifying `$_POST['username']` as a folder too

Comment: @Pablo Lopez, then according to you where it should be placed??

Comment: If you are not getting any errors the problem will be with the permission.. Can you check the folder permission of the directories specified in my answer.

Comment: @asprin yeaa thanks for pointing that out ,, i feel like a dumbass now lmao ,, i wasnt paying attention to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have remove @ before $_FILES and check error.
if you want to replace picture old to new then make your own user wise image name and use it like.

```
$_POST['username']=test;

$imagname=$_POST['username']."_img";

 move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],"userdata/".$_POST['username']."/profilepic/".$imagename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this block of code

```
    $imagename = $_FILES['profilepic']['name'];
    $source = $_FILES['profilepic']['tmp_name'];
    $imagename = str_replace(" ", "_", $imagename);
    $target = "userdata/".$_POST['username']."/profilepic" . $imagename;
    move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
```

Make sure you have got write permission to the folder `userdata`,`plmexico`,`profilepic`.

**Good habits:**

Rename the user's file with a name generated by your algorithm. As you want to replace the profile pic when they upload a new picture you naming can combine `user_id` with the file name. So the code becomes.

```
    $localname = $_FILES['profilepic']['name'];
    $imagename = $user_id."_profile".explode(end(",",$localname)); // $user_id is the user's id
    $source = $_FILES['profilepic']['tmp_name'];
    $imagename = str_replace(" ", "_", $imagename);
    $target = "userdata/".$_POST['username']."/profilepic" . $imagename;
    move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
```

This code doesn't work if the user uploads an image in different format.